# Webservice endpoint is given by glassfish and wildfly but not in jetty

Tags: wsdl, glassfish, jetty, wildfly, jax-ws

I'm developing an application in Java using vaadin, JPA, maven and JAX-WS technologies.
When I publish the application in the **glassfish** server I can see the generated wsdl using this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/at/PrimaryTransmissionService?wsdl
```

When I publish the application in the **wildfly** server I can see the generated wsdl using this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/at-1.0/PrimaryTransmission?wsdl
```

When I publish the application in the jetty server I can't find to which endpoint is deployed, but I can use the webapp by using this url:
http://localhost:8080/at
Could you help me?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using JPA and JAX-WS via Java EE API dependencies relying implementation bundled in Glassfish / Wildfly, which are Java EE compliant application containers, that would explain the observation. That is because Jetty is not Java EE container and does not contain implementation e.g. for JAX-WS out of the box.

Comment: Ohhh... Thanks for the info